# MySQL query failing (create table if not exists)

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ShippingServiceTypes` (
  `serviceTypeCode` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `shippingMethod` VARCHAR(32),
  `serviceTypeFullName` VARCHAR(64),
  `DomesticOrINTL` VARCHAR(32),
  `isEnabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Returns error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 7
```

I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: You have extra comma (`,`)at end of you 'isEnabled' column definition.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a keen eye on the commas at the end of each line. You had one at the end of the last column line. Don't have one there, as there are no lines that follow it prior to closing off the parentheses.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ShippingServiceTypes` (
  `serviceTypeCode` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `shippingMethod` VARCHAR(32),
  `serviceTypeFullName` VARCHAR(64),
  `DomesticOrINTL` VARCHAR(32),
  `isEnabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```